# Naming objects in a python for loop for bootstrapping

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a Pandas dataframe (`df`) with columns for each of the measurements taken on the individuals. There is one row per individual:

| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 2.0 | 4.0 | 5.0 |
| 3.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 | 5.0 |
| 4.0 | 5.0 | 1.0 | 3.0 |
| 5.0 | 5.0 | 4.0 | 4.0 |

My goal is to bootstrap each column to calculate distributions of means. For example, I want to draw a sample (with replacement) each column n times, calculate the mean, and append that mean to a list. Here is the code for one column:

```
mean=[]
for i in np.arange(10000):
    sample = np.random.choice(df['col_1'],size=len(df))
    mean.append(sample.mean())
mean_1 = mean
```

I have done this manually and I am trying to figure out how to loop through the columns. I got stuck in creating object names using the loop iterator. I tried to create objects using the value of `i`, but it won't allow me to assign values to it:

```
for col in df.columns:
       
    mean=[]
    for i in np.arange(10000):
        sample = np.random.choice(df[col],size=len(df))
        mean.append(sample.mean())
    # Need to specify which column mean I am saving: mean_1, mean_2, etc.     
    col+'_mean'= mean
```

This fails because I can't assign values to the combination of `col + '_mean'`. I know there is a straightforward way to do this, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Do you want to add these new `mean` columns to your dataframe?

Comment: wundermahn: No. I figured that I would just end up with a bunch of lists and I'll figure out what to do with those next haha. I definitely won't add them back to the original `df` because they will be different lengths. The output of the bootstrap is 10K long; my `df` is 60. I'll probably combine the `mean_1`, `mean_2`, etc into a different df later.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to store each of your iterations per column and then you might (if you want to) turn into a dataframe:

```
bootstrapped = {}
for col in df: #You don't need to specify .columns           
    mean=[]
    for i in np.arange(10000):
        sample = np.random.choice(df[col],size=len(df))
        mean.append(sample.mean())
    # Need to specify which column mean I am saving: mean_1, mean_2, etc.     
    bootstrapped[col+'_mean'] = mean
```

Then you might use the following to turn the bootstrapped date into a df:

```
bootstrapped_df = pd.DataFrame(bootstrapped)
```

Comment: Also you can do: `for col, series in df.items():`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a function like this:

```
def sample_mean(series, num_sample=1000):
    '''
    sample from `series` and calculate mean for `num_sample` times

    '''
    mean = []  
    for i in np.arange(num_sample):
        # you want to sample with the same length as the data?
        sample = np.random.choice(series, size=len(series))
        mean.append(sample.mean())

    # extract the column name with series.name
    # alternate it, and pass as name of the return series
    return pd.Series(mean, name=series.name+'_mean')


# then call `apply`:
df.apply(sample_mean, num_sample=10000)
```